# Looking for the conditional version (instead of null) of Objects.requireNonNull()

Tags: java, validation, conditional-statements

`Objects.requireNonNull(...)` is a shorthand version of a whole drawn out if statement with a NullPointerException inside the body. Is there any Java equivalent for conditionals? Something like this - `Objects.requireTrue()` where if it is not true, it throws an exception of some sort?

The only alternative I know of is `Assert.assertTrue()`, but I was told to avoid that because assertions can be disabled.

Strong preference for standard library, but 3rd party is fine too. My real goal is to shorten the process of validating a value using a conditional statement.

Comment: The standard Java `assert` keyword can do it;  for example, `assert count >= 0 : "Count cannot be negative.";`.  But assert statements are not executed at all unless explicitly enabled in the Java runtime—either with a command line option, or with a ClassLoader method like [setClassAssertionStatus](https://docs.oracle.com/en/java/javase/17/docs/api/java.base/java/lang/ClassLoader.html#setClassAssertionStatus(java.lang.String,boolean)).

Comment: @VGR Thank you! I do see that, according to the documentation, it throws a very unique type of `Throwable`. Namely, an `AssertionError`. Is there any way to make it throw an `Exception` of some sort? I've currently built my solution around `Exception`, and while I could switch over to catching `Throwable`, I'd like to avoid the extra work.

Comment: I’m not sure I understand your use case.  It is almost never correct to catch `Exception` or `NullPointerException`, since most unchecked exceptions are meant to expose programming mistakes.  The same goes for assertions.  The correct way to avoid those exceptions/errors is to check for invalid conditions before calling the method.

Comment: If you use Guava (Google's framework library), it provides the `Preconditions` class, which supports many useful static methods, for example `checkState(<boolean condition>, "This value is bad: %s", theBadValue);`  See https://guava.dev/releases/19.0/api/docs/com/google/common/base/Preconditions.html

Comment: @VGR I see, in which case, Assertions work perfectly, thank you!

Comment: @Gene that is great, thank you very much!